# Dive in second activity causes location and Location Listener error

Tags: java, android, google-maps

cannot be cast to `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` my main problem is that after passing the login does't dive to second activity app crashes some one help me identify the problem where it comes from is it my layout or ...!!

locgat

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.logo.tm.androiddriverapp.Welcome cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
                         at com.logo.tm.androiddriverapp.Welcome.startLocationUpdate(Welcome.java:532)
                         at com.logo.tm.androiddriverapp.Welcome.onConnected(Welcome.java:571)
                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzae.zzk(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzba.zzj(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzao.zzaie(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzao.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbi.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzt.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.onConnected(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzakr(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzw(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzaks(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=Welcome, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-5990294920665317261,
```

Here is the welcome layout code dont know if there is some thing abnomal:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_panel"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_panel"
        tools:context="com.logo.tm.androidapp.Welcome" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
                android:id="@+id/location_switch"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:icon_release="@drawable/ic_location_off"
                app:icon_press="@drawable/ic_location_on"
                app:base_release_color="@color/baseReleaseColor"
                app:base_press_color="@color/basePressColor"
                app:ball_release_color="@color/ballReleaseColor"
                app:ball_press_color="@android:color/white"  />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_find_user"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:text="FIND RIDERS"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

java welcome class
sorry no more space on my body here is the link to the code

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v6Frd1fHB_m65z2Sg74a9qERS2Llmiyu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: add your java code

Comment: just added suraj

Answer (score 0):

Replace this: `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);`

with this:

```
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);
```

And Replace This:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
```

with this:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest, this);
```

I mean just remove `(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)`, because you already implemented LocationListener,you don't need to cast.

Comment: thanks it walked i could get to the activity but now i have a problem when ever i request a location for showing route parth to that locationrequested it get crash i code it at java class lease can you help me out with that

Answer (score 0):

promlem is in your imported library at the top part of the class, it shouldto be 
  `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` not import `android.location.LocationListener;` replace this.

Comment: but htis give me error at public void onStatusChanged ,public void onProviderEnabled , public void onProviderDisabled how can i solve this please

Comment: have you implemented  LocationListener as public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener

Comment: remove nStatusChanged ,public void onProviderEnabled , public void onProviderDisabled and import them again. it will solve your problem

Comment: thanks 2 u guys it walked i could get to the activity but now i have a problem when ever i request a location for showing route parth to that locationrequested it get crash i code it at java class lease can you help me out with that

Comment: mean while i activated all api related